# Can we Control/Restrict Page Region access via User Groups?

Tags: sdl-tridion, event-system

We want to enforce some mandatory regions on the page level which should be inherited by all the child publications.

However, these mandatory regions should only be editable in the parent publication.

Can someone provide any pointers, how can we achieve this?

We are using SDL9 + DXA 2.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have Page Regions which are:

- Separately BluePrinted (the Regions may be shared from the parent Publication, whereas the Page itself is not).
- Separately Secured (a user which is allowed to edit the Page may not be allowed to edit those Regions).

If so, it sounds like you want to use Include Pages for those Regions. That is a concept offered by DXA, where separate Pages in CM act as Regions in the DXA Page Model.

See https://docs.sdl.com/784837/695656/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/page-includes-as-page-regions